# $f$ continuous on $[0, \infty)$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = L \in \Bbb R$, prove $f$ achieves a minimum

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I = [0, \infty)$, and  $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = L \in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove that if $\exists x_0 \geq 0: f(x_0) = L$, then $f$ achieves a minimum value on $I$.

Would someone be able to give me a direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ attains a minimum in the compact interval $[0,x_0]$, at $\xi_0$ say. So if we can show that $f$ also attains a minimum in $[x_0,\infty)$, at $\xi_1$ say, then we know that $f$ attains a minimum in $[0,\infty)$, at either $\xi_0$ or $\xi_1$.

If $f(x)\ge f(x_0)$ for all $x>x_0$, then $f$ attains a minimum in $[x_0,\infty)$, at $x_0$. So we may assume that there exists $\xi_2>x_0$ such that $f(\xi_2)<f(x_0)$. And because $f(x)\to L$ as $x\to\infty$, there must exist $M$ such that $f(x)>f(\xi_2)$ whenever $x>M$.

But $[x_0,M]$ is compact, so $f$ attains a minimum on this interval; and the point where it attains this minimum is our $\xi_1$. QED.

Comment: Thank you, but: 

1. if $\forall x > x_0: f(x) > f(x_0)$

2. Then you say $\exists \xi_2 > 0: f(\xi_2) < f(x_0)$ but that is a contradiction to $\forall x > x_0: f(x) > f(x_0)$ you just said.

Comment: I didn't say that $\forall x > x_0: f(x) > f(x_0)$. I said: "_If_ $f(x)\ge f(x_0)$ for all $x>x_0$..." then we are done. So assume that this is _not_ the case, and...etc.

Comment: Understood, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the function $f$ does not have a minimum. Then, specifically, the point $x_0$ is not a minimum, to there is a point $x_1 > x_0 + 1$ such that $f(x_1) > f(x_0).$

Indeed, if there were no such point, then $f(x) \leq f(x_0)$ for all $x > x_0 + 1$. The interval $[0,x_0+1]$ is compact. so $f$ **attains** a minimum (say $f(y_0)$) on this interval. Taking $l = \min{f(x_0),f(y_0)}$ is then a minimum for $f$ on $[0,\infty)$, a contradiction.

You can continue this process by induction to obtain a sequence $x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots$, where e.g. $x_2 > x_1 + 1$ and $f(x_2) > f(x_1)$. By construction, $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty$, so by continuity of $f$, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = L$.

However, the sequence $f(x_n)$ is strictly increasing, with $f(x_0) > L$. This is a contradiction with the above, so $f$ must have a minimum.

Comment: The second paragraph looks wrong to me. Why can't there exist $x_2>x_0+1$ such that $f(x_2)<l$? I think you must have got one of your inequalities the wrong way around.

Comment: I think you are right. Probably the argument can be fixed by trying to instead construct a point with f(x_1) < f (x_0). That makes the second paragraph correct, and it gives a monotone decreasing sequence instead. It that works out, I will edit the response tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=f(\tan x)$ for $0\leq x <\frac {\pi} 2$. Then $g$ is continuous and $\lim_{x \to \frac {\pi} 2}  g(x)=L$. Hence we can extend $g$ to a  continuous function on $[0,\frac {\pi} 2]$. Also $g(s)=L$ for  some $s <\frac {\pi} 2$. This implies that $g$ has a minimum at some point $t <\frac {\pi} 2$. [For this look at the minimum of $g$ on $[s,\frac {\pi} 2]$].  Now that $f$ has a minimum at $\tan t$.